# Azure Functions node PM 4 doesn't detect my functions

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure-functions

I just switched my existing project to the new programming model v4 using [this migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-node-upgrade-v4?tabs=vs-code-set-indexing-flag%2Cv4). I love the idea that I can structure my directories and files as I want, but it doesn't seem to work.
My folder structure (src is in the root of the function project, alongside dist):

```
src
+---functions
|   +---criteria
|   |   |   create.ts
|   |   |   getall.ts
|   |   |   getone.ts
|   |   |
|   |   \---types
|   |           createCriteria.dto.ts
|   |
|   +---events
|   |       getall.ts
|   |
|   \---ratings
|       |   create.ts
|       |   getcriteria.ts
|       |   rateone.ts
|       |
|       \---types
|               createRating.dto.ts
|
\---lib ...
```

The main property in `package.json` (and yes, there is an src directory inside dist):

```json
"main": "dist/src/functions/**/*.js"
```

However, when I start the app locally, I get the following warning:

```
"No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.)."
```

My function files all look simething like this...

```js
import { HttpRequest, HttpResponseInit, InvocationContext, app } from '@azure/functions'

export const getCriteria = async (req: HttpRequest, context: InvocationContext): Promise<HttpResponseInit> => {
  ...
  return { body: ... }
}

app.http('ratings-getcriteria', {
  methods: ['GET'],
  route: 'ratings/{id}',
  handler: getCriteria
})
```

What am I missing?

I also tried creating a function in `src/functions` and using the same glob patter as in the tutorial (`dist/src/functions/*.js`), but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Azure Functions Core Tools was too old on my machine. Programming model v4 requires v4.0.5095 or newer.